# C# how do you print words that start with a specific letter from a .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have this method `GetWordsArray` below, and when I call the method in the main program it only prints out whole sentences which start with the specific letter of that whole sentence.

```
public static void GetWordsArray(string path, string toFind)
{
    string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    if (File.Exists(path)) 
    {              
        foreach (string line in words)
        {
            if(line.StartsWith(toFind))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }                  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
    }
}
```

This is what it prints out from the txt file:

> oranges you have no red plums on a little nutmeg. RAGOUT OF LAMB A GOOD RISSOLES Mince some artichoke-bottoms cooked by rolling the yellow aspic, and throw them a five-franc piece.

I want it to print it like this if the specific letter is an `o` for example:
`oranges` `OF` etc.

This is how I call the method in the main program:

```
Reader r = new Reader();            
string path = @"randomtext.txt";
Reader.GetWordsArray(path, "o");
```

How can I print out all the words from the text file which start with the letter o for example?

Comment: _string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path);_ is returning an array of lines in the file, not an array of words. You need to split each line - on space & punctuation. You probably want a non-case sensitive comparison too : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textfile has only 1 line it seems, and since your long sentence starts with an `o` it prints the entire line. Either you format your file so that every word is situated on a single line or you split each line and iterate through the elements and do your checking there:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    foreach (string line in words)
    {
        string [] elements = line.Split(' ');
        foreach (string elem in elements)
        {
            if (elem.StartsWith(toFind))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(elem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now the only output should be **oranges** and **on**

Comment: It still prints out whole sentences x4, I only want it per word. Is there a way I can split each individual word on each line?

Comment: I got it, but you printed out: line instead of: elem. So it needs to be: Console.WriteLine(elem);

Comment: @meesie1 sorry for that, silly copy paste mistake. changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you read every line you need to split every line in words and search in every word your string. You can do it in this way:

```
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                if (word.StartsWith(toFind))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
    }
```

And also check `File.Exists(path)` before calling `File.ReadAllLines(path)`

Comment: What is the reason why you need to call the: `File.Exists(path)` first?

Comment: @meesie1 File.ReadAllLines(path) will throw FileNotFoundException if file is not exists

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading line one by one use [File.ReadAllText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) to have as input your whole file. like this:

```
string input = 
    @"oranges you have no red plums on a little nutmeg. RAGOUT OF LAMB A GOOD RI
    oranges you have no red plums on a little nutmeg. RAGOUT OF LAMB A GOOD RI
    oranges you have no red plums on a little nutmeg. RAGOUT OF LAMB A GOOD RI
    SSOLES Mince some artichoke-bottoms cooked by rolling the yellow asp
    ic, and throw them a five-franc piece.";
```

Slipt this text on Space and Environnement newline and line what you are looking for:

```
var arrayOfWord= input.Split(  new[] { " ","\r\n", "\n" }
                             , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string toFind = "o";
var result = arrayOfWord.Where(y=> y.StartsWith(toFind));
```

You now have your list of word. And if you want to print them, a simple foreach should do the trick.